# Flip cards to get maximum sum

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given N cards where if ith card has number x on its front side then it will have -x on back side and a single operation that can be done only once that is to flip any number of cards in consecutive order only once.

Now we need to flip cards in such a way that sum of number of upper face of cards is maximum.

Example : If N=5 and cards[] be {-2,3,-1,-4,-2} then here answer is 8 as we can flip last 3 cards to get configuration {-2,3,1,4,2} which sum to 8.

My Approach :

Go for each possible way for each ith position as start position and find the maximum.But is their any better solution to this problem?

My Code : Am not able to find problem till yet

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int solve(std::vector<int> const & numbers)
{
    int min_so_far  = numbers[0], min_ending_here = numbers[0];
    size_t begin = 0;
    size_t begin_temp = 0;
    size_t end = 0;
    for(size_t i = 1; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
            if(min_ending_here > 0)
            {
                    min_ending_here = numbers[i];
                    begin_temp = i;
            }
            else
            {
                    min_ending_here += numbers[i];
            }

            if(min_ending_here <= min_so_far )
            {
                    min_so_far  = min_ending_here;
                    begin = begin_temp;
                    end = i;
            }
    }
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<begin;i++){
        sum+=numbers[i];
    }
    for(int i=begin;i<=end;i++){
        sum-=numbers[i];
    }
    for(int i=end+1;i<numbers.size();i++){
        sum+=numbers[i];
    }
    return sum;

}
int main(){
int n;
cin>>n;
vector<int> arr;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    arr.push_back(x);
}

  cout<<solve(arr)<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: @VotetoClose This is an algorithmic question that has nothing to do with math: at the most, it requires some exposure to arithmetic.

Comment: If you partition your array into positive and negative segments you really only need to test the start of each negative segment, all the way until the end of said negative segment.

Comment: @Ben Not really: the answer to `-3, 2, -4` is 5 (flip everything), so you cannot stop flipping at the end of the first negative segment.

Comment: @Ben Are you sure it will serve the purpose ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yeah right..

Comment: @Ben Not so: consider {1, -2, -3, -4, 1, 1, -99, 1}.

Comment: I see I wasn't thinking, I didn't see the need to flip positive numbers

Comment: Do you *have* to flip a certain number of cards, or will *up-to-and-including* a certain number be acceptable?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Its not anything that i need to flip certain number of cards

Comment: Are you saying that, given {1, -2, -3, -4, 1, 1, -99, 1} and `nFlipsMaximum = 3`, you can choose to flip *only* the -99 value?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: As far as I see, there is no `nFlipsMaximum` in his question. The only condition is that you can only flip one group of consecutive cards (however short/long it might be).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing you need to find is the minimum sum that you can form with consecutive numbers, and then flip those. In your example, the last three numbers add up to -7, and there is no other set of consecutive number which have a lower sum, so flipping them does the trick. If the minimum sum is non negative, then you don't need to flip them.

Now, what I described above is a well known algorithm, and it is called [Kadane's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem), which can be solve in O(n), notice that the Wikipedia link shows how to do it for the maximum, but you can easily modify it to find the minimum.

Comment: @user3878046 I believe the line if(min_ending_here < 0) should be if(min_ending_here > 0)

Answer (score -1):

I used Kadane's algorithm approach in this and the Minimum Subarray Sum function returns the minimum sum in `O(n)` and since we already had the sum of all elements of the array so we will add (-2) time of `min_sum` as it was deducted once.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int minsubarraysum(int a[], int n) {
    int min_sum = INT_MAX;
    int curr_sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
        curr_sum = curr_sum + a[i];
        if (curr_sum < min_sum)
            min_sum = curr_sum;
        if (curr_sum > 0)
            curr_sum  = 0;
    }

    return min_sum;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
        sum += a[i];
    }
    int min_sum = minsubarraysum(a, n);
    int ans = sum + (min_sum * (-2));
    cout << ans;

}
```

Comment: I used Kadane's algorithm approach in this and the Minimum Subarray Sum function returns the minimum sum in O(n) and since we already had the sum of all elements of the array so we will add (-2) time of min_sum as it was deducted once. And you will get the correct answer :)